# how to do $id + 1 with every form submit?

Tags: php, forms, session, form-submit

I want to add dynamic session variables. So I start with id=0 but after I submit the form the id must be set to 1 and the next to 2 etc. Down here is what i tried. I tried to do a $id++ in the if submit function, but that's not working.

```
        <?php
        $id = 0; 
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $_SESSION['person'][$id] = array(   
                                                'id' =>  $id,
                                                'voornaam' => $_POST['firstname'], 
                                                'achternaam' => $_POST['lastname'], 
                                                'leeftijd' => $_POST['age'], 
                                                'rol' => $_POST['role'],
                                                'omschrijving' => $_POST['description'],
                                            );
            $id++;
            header('Location: mysite');
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Instead of counting you could also do this: `$_SESSION['person'][] = array()`

Comment: $id exists only for the duration of your script, and you continually reset it to `0` anyways. After you do `$id++` and the script exits, the variable is destroyed, and gets reinitialized to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$id = count($_SESSION['person']);
```

(Assuming that you have defined `$_SESSION['person']` as an array elsewhere.)

Complete snippet looks like this:

```
if (!is_array($_SESSION['person']))
{
    $_SESSION['person'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $id                      = count($_SESSION['person']);
    $_SESSION['person'][$id] = array(
        'id'           => $id,
        'voornaam'     => $_POST['firstname'],
        'achternaam'   => $_POST['lastname'],
        'leeftijd'     => $_POST['age'],
        'rol'          => $_POST['role'],
        'omschrijving' => $_POST['description'],
    );
    header('Location: mysite');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually persisting the value anywhere.  So it's going to reset to 0 every time.

You create the value every time:

```
$id = 0;
```

And you increment it:

```
$id++;
```

But you don't keep it anywhere.  If the value is supposed to follow the user's session, keep it in the session.  Something like:

```
// get the id from session, or create a new one
$id = 0;
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
}

// use the id value in your code

// increment the id and store it back in the session
$_SESSION['id'] = $id + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand you clearly, but this might help

```
<?php
    $id = 0; 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $currID = $_SESSION['person']['id'];
        $_SESSION['person'] = array(   
                                    'id' =>  $currID++,
                                    'voornaam' => $_POST['firstname'], 
                                    'achternaam' => $_POST['lastname'], 
                                    'leeftijd' => $_POST['age'], 
                                    'rol' => $_POST['role'],
                                    'omschrijving' => $_POST['description'],
                                );
        header('Location: mysite');
    }
?>
```